# Why I get three undefined things and why there are two outputs in one call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, asynchronous, async-await

I'm new to react. So I'm developing a application which gets data from a api. So I used this piece of code to get data from a api.

```
let [jsonData,setJsonData]=useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(apiURL);
            const json = await response.json();
            setJsonData(json.components.map(function(item){
                return item;
            }))
        } catch (error) { }
    }
    fetchData();
    
}, [])
const [table1,table2,pieChart]=jsonData;
console.log(table1,table2,pieChart)
```

This is the **problem**. When I run this I get a output like this.

[image: This is the problem]

In this **why there are two outputs in the first call and in first output why I get 3 undefined things**.I just need to get the only those JSON data in the first call.**How do I get the required data only and not to get those undefined things.**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can't avoid the fact that your fetch function is asynchronous, but you  can do something like this:

```
if (!jsonData.length) return <div>loading...</div>;
```

Comment: Is there any way to wait other processes until I get the data from the api?

Comment: @TharinduGimras you can create a wrapper higher-level component that waits for something to complete and only render the sub-component when the data is there. Or you can use 'suspense'. Both of those are pretty complex though. I'd strongly recommend you start with the easy version. Just don't render until the data is there. It's literally 1 if statement.

Comment: Thanks so much I got the point. I will do that.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing an asynchronous request in your useEffect function, which means that your fetch function will run parallel to the current code but it will finish sometime after. So the first time you console.log those values the useEffect has not finished yet. At the end of your useEffect you used the setJsonData, which will make the component re-render with the updated state, hence this is why you see the second console.log with the correct values at last.

Comment: Ah. That's why I'm getting two outputs like that. Is there any way to wait until I get those correct values?

Comment: You can fetch this data in a parent component and only render this component when those values are not undefined.